# I am unable to use special characters of row which has numbers on the top of keypad?

Tags: system-installation

When I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>, instead of giving hash <kbd>#</kbd> symbol it gives some other special character. What should i do to correct it ?

Answer (score 0):

You must check your Keyboard Layout. Follow the steps below:

1. Click on, <kbd>En</kbd> symbol on the left of your battery symbol in the panel on the top.
2. Then, select *Text Entry Settings*.
3. Check, under the *Input Sources* section, there is a entry for `English (US)`.
   If not, then click the <kbd>+</kbd> button to add it from the list of available Keyboard Layouts.
4. Type In, `English US` and the click <kbd>Add</kbd> button.
5. Also, Remove any other layout available in the list except `English (US)`.

Comment: @AshutoshVerma Tell me if that worked